# Can a dynamic username used as an object in django to access class members?

Tags: python, django, class, object

In views.py,

```
def func(request):
    request.POST['username'] = cls()
    request.POST['username'].clsfunc()
    print(request.POST['username'].var)


class cls():
    var = 0
    def clsfunc(self):
         self.var += 1
```

Will this work and print 1 in the console?

Comment: Why would it print? You have not called `print` anywhere in the code

Comment: @Sid Since this is a django code, the function `func()` will be provoked in `urls.py` and I haven't mentioned it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `request.POST[]` is immutable this won't work. This can be solved by,

```
        g = globals()
        g["Anystring" + str(request.POST['username'])] = cls()
        g["Anystring" + str(request.POST['username'])].clsfunc()
```

Creating object directly with the `POST()` won't work

Answer (score 0):

Although `self.var` can refer to the class attribute `var` when the name `var` does not exist as an instance attribute, it is forced to be an instance attribute when assigned a value in an assignment, so:

```
self.var += 1
```

would assign `cls.var + 1` to `self.var`, rather than `cls.var`.

You can either make it:

```
cls.var += 1
```

Or to be more generic, find the class of the current instance object first:

```
self.__class__.var += 1
```

Comment: So this should go as cls.var += 1 in clsfunc() right?